# Testing instructions for updating addon

Tags: office-store

I want to update my addon (cannot reveal the name here). I uploaded a new package and published it. In the certification phase it was invalidated with reasons:
 1. Not enough test instructions provided.

My question: How am I supposed to add instructions? Is it the optional textbox that we get when clicking 'publish' button?

Answer (score 0):

When you select 'review and publish' from the top right in your partner center account, the 'notes for certification' field will be available before you resubmit the offer.